# Kong Streaming: JSON Transcoding with GRPC-Gateway

Tags: grpc, kong, grpc-gateway

I would like to stream a video using grpc microservice.
My client will make an HTTP request to Kong Gateway and the gateway will transcode the HTTP JSON request to GRPC.

I read that GRPC-Gateway doesn't support stream.
Should I move to another API Gateway then (like Tyk?)
If I really have to move to another API Gateway, why people says Kong is so good while I can't even do GRPC streaming HTTP transcoding?
Is there another solution between client <-HTTP-> Kong <-> MicroServices communication ?
Is GRPC-Web more used than Grpc-Gateway?

PS: I am still a newbie with microservices.